# How to generate .classpath container entry(all dependencies in gradle cache) for java project in vscode using gradle eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, visual-studio-code

I'm using `VSCode` for java project, and I fonud that if there is no `.classpath` file, `VSCode` wouldn't find the proper path of dependencies and gave errors. So I used `gradle eclipse` to generate it.

The basic `.classpath` file generated by `gradle eclipse` shown as follow:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="bin/main" path="src/main/resources">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_scope" value="main"/>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="main,test"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="bin/test" path="src/test/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_scope" value="test"/>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="test"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="bin/test" path="src/test/resources">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_scope" value="test"/>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="test"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8/"/>
</classpath>
```

After adding some dependencies in build.gradle, I run `gradle build` and `gradle eclipse`, the `.classpath` file regenerated with all the dependencies I've added, but they are shown as follow:

```xml
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-client/3.2.0/64e71497e5cb87e3cae9063d9899bc102c540384/hadoop-client-3.2.0.jar" sourcepath="C:/Users/xiaohu10/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-client/3.2.0/948488c756ae3707ce143f98e930f678e434291c/hadoop-client-3.2.0-sources.jar">
...
```

We can notice that gradle use the absolute path of all denpendencies with hard code, resulting in a very large `.classpath` file.

I want to do the same thing like the JRE entry using a container `<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8/"/>`.

Can gradle define a classpath `container` which containes all the dependencies from gradle cache? Just like `buildship` does on eclipse `<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.buildship.core.gradleclasspathcontainer"/>`

Thanks~

Comment: maybe you could copy the jar files,put them into lib folder,and set in .Classpath like <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/xxx.jar">

Comment: But I want to manage the jars with gradle, not add jars to project mannually. Is there any gradle plugins could do this?